# Check if procedural macro is running in IDE or build process

Tags: rust

I'm using a procedural macro to transform a struct + impl into a format compatible with a third party framework, but I need to generate files describing these bindings, which will be consumed by the third party framework.

Is there a way to check if a procedural macro is running due to `cargo build/check/etc`, or within an IDE?

##### Background

I need to do this because I'm trying to run unit tests written in Rust from Godot, but it needs a wrapper script written in gdscript, which will call the unit test functions. I don't want the files to be re-written every time my IDE re-parses my code.

I'm using rust-analyzer and vscode, although I doubt this will make a difference.

Comment: I don't believe you can tell the difference in what context the code is being built. What I would suggest is use a environment variable (or maybe a cargo feature) that can change what your macro does.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand why any (source) files get rewritten when your IDE executes the proc macro?  Surely any proc macro expansion only happens in-memory?  Or are you referring to the incremental compilation cache?  If the latter, perhaps your IDE and Godot can use different caches?

Comment: If I have a macro X that operates on function, then emits some data containing the function name to a file, whenever the IDE runs the procedural macro to see what the resulting source would be, it would behave the same. I only want the macro to emit the file when I build it.From what I see, rust-analyzer just runs the macro the same as rustc and doesn't do any simulation of the macro code.

Comment: How it will help you if you'll know whether it is running? You can tell rust-analyzer to ignore this macro.

Comment: Having a proc macro write to the file system smells a bit, to my mind.  My gut says you might be better performing those actions from a Cargo build script, which can be configured not to rerun unless particular files have been modified since the last run?  But that might involve quite a bit of redesign and rework.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman  The macro isn't just used for reflection the impl. It also transforms the struct and does a lot of validation.

Comment: @eggyal  Is there a way to have a build script behave the same as a macro? (ie iterate an impl block at the token level). Because if there is, I agree that it would probably be a good idea to use it instead.

Comment: I think with a build script it’d be more normal to approach from a different direction, which may or may not suit your requirements: eg have the build script generate (from some input, whether hard coded in the script or configurable through some input file) both the existing data file and also a Rust source file (containing the impl block or whatever).